# Working with PHP Explode, and FOREACH - getting various errors with each type of an attempt

Tags: php, arrays, string, foreach

I am bringing in some data through `$form_data = $_POST['form_data'];`. I am needing to loop through this data for each value so I thought foreach might be what I want. So I start with:

`vardump($form_data`) and see: `string(125) "Customer_FName=r&Customer_LName=r&Customer_MobileNumber=2&Customer_Email=r%40rco.com&Reservation_Message=&C_Preference_Notes=" 0`

Cool. So its coming in as a string. Sounds like a job for `$form_data_array=json_decode($form_data);`

( I set the type as JSON in the AJAX) but This gives me: "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in ....... NULL 0"

The code :

```
    $form_data = $_POST['form_data'];
$form_data_array=json_decode($form_data);
    foreach ($form_data_array as $key => $data){
        $data->Customer_FName;
        $data->Customer_LName;
        $data->Customer_MobileNumber;
        $data->Customer_Email;
        $data->C_Preference_Notes;
    };
```

Odd so maybe its a better job for `explode`.
So: `$form_data_array = explode("& ",$form_data);`
That gives me the error of "Trying to get property 'Customer_FName' of non-object ".
I `vardump($form_data_array) and see it has split it right

```
array(6) { [0]=> string(16) "Customer_FName=r" [1]=> string(16) "Customer_LName=r" [2]=> string(23) "Customer_MobileNumber=2" [3]=> string(24) "Customer_Email=w%402.com" [4]=> string(20) "Reservation_Message=" [5]=> string(19) "C_Preference_Notes=" } 0
```

but still get the "Trying to get property '...' of non-object"

Ok so now I am getting somewhere! I change my code to be:

```
$form_data = $_POST['form_data'];
$form_data_array = explode("&", $form_data);
foreach ($form_data_array as $key => $data){
    $data[Customer_FName];
    $data[Customer_LName];
    $data[Customer_MobileNumber];
    $data[Customer_Email];
    $data[C_Preference_Notes];
};
```

But I get errors for each of the "for each" of - "Warning: Illegal string offset 'Customer_FName' in ... on line ..."

AND

Warning: Use of undefined constant Customer_LName - assumed 'Customer_LName' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in ... on line ..."

Back to the decode with the explode?

And now I am out of ideas. What am I missing here?

The AJAX

```
        jQuery(document).on('submit', '#ajax-add-to', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
            var form = jQuery('#ajax-add-to');
            var form_data = form.serialize();
                        jQuery.ajax({
                        data: {action:'myaction',
                              form_data:form_data},
                            type: 'post',
                            url: my_ajax.ajax_url,
                            dataType: 'JSON',                           
                            success: function(data){
                                      if(data.status == 'error'){
        console.log("[API] ERROR: "+data.message);
      }
      if(data.status == 'success'){
        console.log("[API] SUCCESS: "+data.message);
      }
                            }

}); 
    return false;
        
    });
```

Comment: What you have is a query string. You can decode it using `parse_str($form_data, $data);`, `$data` will then be an array of the values indexed by the names

Comment: need to see some of your html form to know what to expect. But it’s not json, and it’s not an array. It looks more like a query string, but why is it in 'form_data'? Do you have mod_rewrite sending POST data as a query string in 'form_data'?

Comment: @Nick I’m curious how OP is getting a query string here. I can’t think of anything other than a redirect... or a bad Ajax call. Just curious if you have some educated guesses; seems like that’s the real issue, even if that’s not the question asked.

Comment: @TimMorton it is a good question and definitely the real issue; without seeing their ajax call code it's hard to be sure, but perhaps they're generating a query string and passing that as the post parameter instead of passing the raw data?

Comment: Hi Tim. Thanks. As Nick says its AJAX coming from a form that passes it through. I have added the AJAX above to show.

Comment: @nick thanks but then when trying to use it in a MYSQL statement I am getting errors of undefined offset or undefined variable since I can not use the output information of the `parse_str` in a `foreach` statement

Comment: I don't understand why you are using a foreach loop on the output of `parse_str`. You should just be using the individual elements e.g. `$data['Customer_FName']` where you need them

Comment: @theodore for example see https://3v4l.org/dA5VD

Comment: Much appreciated but this is still throwing errors. Undefined offset. I have tried `$c_duplicate_check=$wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Customer_FName='".$data['Customer_FName']. "'"));` and a lot of others including `$test=$data['Customer_FName'];` and then using that with or without quotes etc. I am really struggling with the fact this is still a string.